# Building Angular in Docker throws "environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist"

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

The following Dockerfile throws an error when I try to build it.
I also tried with a RUN command to install the angular/cli globally and call with another RUN `ng build --prod` directly, but the same error occurs.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.17.0-alpine AS build-angular
WORKDIR /src
COPY webui/* webui/
WORKDIR /src/webui
RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

**Build Error Output**

```sh
Step 6/6 : RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
 ---> Running in 0fb33e92b742

> webui@0.0.0 build /src/webui
> ng build --prod

An unhandled exception occurred: The /src/webui/src/environments/environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist.
See "/tmp/ng-fiLpfO/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! webui@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webui@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-28T11_18_53_532Z-debug.log
The command 'npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Excerpt from angular.json**

```
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the * from the COPY line.
The following DOCKERFILE works:

```
FROM node:12.17.0-alpine AS build-angular
WORKDIR /src
COPY webui ./
RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

The * is not needed as mentioned in the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> If  is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to permissions, if you are using MAC or Linux. I managed to solve the issue by adding my project folder and parent folder to File Sharing list. Just go to Docker -> Preferences -> Resources -> File sharing and make sure your project folder is included in the list.