# Dockerizing Angular app: The /app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to dockerize an Angular app. Below is the dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM node:alpine AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY *.json ./
COPY *.js ./
COPY src .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=build /app/dist .
```

And below is `angular.json` config:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "web": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "web:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "web:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "web:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "web"
}
```

What's the reason it throws the following error on 9th step? I tried to look for this error in the internet, and found couples of resources ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62063567) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/nsajie/an_unhandled_exception_occurred/)), but those aren't of any help to me.

```
Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
An unhandled exception occurred: The /app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts path in file replacements does not exist.
See "/tmp/ng-PPmHPI/angular-errors.log" for further details.
unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 127. Please fix the Dockerfile and try again..
```

> The error seems pretty much self-explanatory, but note that I have that file in that specified path. So the error must be causing for something else.

Comment: add `RUN ls -la /app/src/environments/` before the `npm run build` and attach the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed to reflect the exact same data structure. Instead of

```dockerfile
COPY src .
```

It has to be

```dockerfile
COPY src ./src
```

Thanks to @jrichardsz for hinting me with some debug steps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was folder and file permissions:

[image]

Somehow src folder was not accessible. I fixed with

```
sudo chmod 700 src -R
```